# "Отлично сделали, молодец!" — согласование

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

> Вы всё это отлично сделали, молодец!

*В таком виде фраза вроде естественно звучит.* А если сказать короче, зная, что собеседник из предыдущего контекста понимает что к чему? ***Отлично сделали, молодец!***

Пояснять, думаю не надо, что здесь обращение на вы. Некоторые нерусские или не очень грамотные люди говорят, обращаясь к одному человеку, *"молодцы",* но мы-то с вами знаем, что это неправильно.

Будет ли последняя фраза нормально звучать, несмотря на разное число глагола и обращения? Можно так упрощать хотя бы в тех случаях, когда уверен, что собеседник правильно тебя поймёт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Отлично сделали, молодец!***

Я думаю, что без местоимения ВЫ такая фраза звучит не совсем корректно, так как в ней слышится **оттенок фамильярности.**

Причем этот оттенок, как мне кажется,  **звучит практически всегда**, если местоимения ВЫ нет рядом, например: *Вы отлично сделали, молодец!*

Поэтому правильно будет так: *Вы молодец, отлично всё сделали.*

**Пример:** Гюстав Флобер скучен, но вы молодец, поставили очень интересно... [Вениамин Смехов. Театр моей памяти (2001)]

Сравнить: *Гюстав Флобер скучен, но вы поставили очень интересно, молодец!*

Comment: Спасибо большое!